# Angular6 Material design issue

Tags: angular6

I am working on angular6. Recently installed the libraries regarding the angular material, and import it in appropriate files like in `style.css`:

```
@import "~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css";
```

in `app.module.ts` it's imported and in `app.component.html` it is as well

```
<md-checkbox>subscribe</md-checkbox>
```

but on front-end i am getting the blank screen and in console i am getting the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object(...) is not a function
    at platform.es5.js:102
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/platform.es5.js (platform.es5.js:104)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/cdk/esm5/a11y.es5.js (a11y.es5.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../node_modules/@angular/material/esm5/checkbox.es5.js (checkbox.es5.js:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/app/app.module.ts (app.component.ts:8)
    at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:78)
    at Module../src/main.ts (main.ts:1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue (long time ago) by including the styles in `angular.json` and not in `styles.scss`:

```
"styles": [
    "./node_modules/@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/indigo-pink.css",
    "src/sass/styles.scss"
],
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're confusing Material for AngularJS and Angular.

I think you should be using this: `<mat-checkbox>Subscribe</mat-checkbox>` instead of `md-checkbox`.